# Did Mark Hamill know about the theatrical ending of The Last Jedi?

Tags: star-wars, behind-the-scenes, the-last-jedi

Given Mark Hamill's criticism of how Luke Skywalker's character was handled, was the ending of the film kept from him?  There is growing speculation that his reaction after the film indicated that he may have been hurt/enraged/shocked by the ending.  Has this ever been confirmed by the actor?

Here's some examples of claims that the actor didn't know about the characters fate.

Mark Hamill didn't know The Last Jedi's ending

[Mark Hamill didn't know Luke's fate](http://www.mixedmartialarts.com/forums/OtherGround/Mark-Hamill-didnt-know-Lukes-fate:2693857)

Comment: Can you provide an example of where he disagrees with the ending? Everything I've seen thus far is about the middle part with a depressedLuke who cut and ran.

Comment: @FuzzyBoots I can't.  That's what I'm asking for.  I've seen many interviews about his disillusionment with the characterization with Luke.  I'm asking if he ever mentioned how he was surprised or disappointed by the ending.

Comment: if the process for The Force Awakens is any indication, then part of the pre-production process probably included a sit-down script read-through with the entire cast. It is unlikely Hamill didn't know what would happen to Luke

Comment: @NKCampbell I'd say of all movie franchises, Star Wars is the one most famous for keeping it's actors in the dark about surprises or twists, and getting more notorious for major changes in post-production.  And of course the claim that is made is exactly that -- that Luke Skywalker dying at the end was added in post production. The way it was shown, Mark Hamill certainly didn't have to know in order to film that scene.  He didn't even have to be in it.

Comment: This video is pretty poor in that it repeatedly shows the same scenes (I think) of Mark Hamill looking upset without ever letting us here what he actually says.

Comment: @PJTraill Yeah, you're right.  I guess when I'm upset, I just wish that others I hold in esteem were upset with me, so I hoped this would be true, but it seems like a really clickbait-y video I never should've watched

Comment: Thanks for your remark, bad luck falling for the clickbait (always annoying when it happens) and sorry about the homophone here/hear. I think it was worth asking the question anyway.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

[Mark Hamill did debunk this rumor on Twitter](http://comicbook.com/starwars/2017/12/30/star-wars-the-last-jedi-rumor-ending-changed-mark-hamill/), stating:

> The idea that ANYTHING was revealed "last minute at the premiere" is ridiculous  &  one of the nuttiest lies I've seen on social media! It was ALL in the script from Day 1.

The footage of Mark Hamill "after the premiere" [has been taken out of context as it was footage from the press conference tour](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=4S6iJpJ752A) which was filmed on the 3rd of December 2017, not the actual premiere which was on 9 December 2017.

Comment: In the words of the immortal [Tom Pepper](http://seinfeld.wikia.com/wiki/Tom_Pepper), They *fooled* me, Jerry!